# Node JS: Listening for HTTPS POST JSON Requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, https

I currently have a network server that is posting information to me as JSON payloads to a specific URL endpoint.

The specification states I need to standup an HTTPS server that can listen for POST JSON requests.

I've created the simple Node JS listener shown below.

I can confirm the request is hitting the endpoint, but when logged, appears to be garbled data. Can someone please tell me if I'm missing a parameter in my script that is preventing the JSON decoding from happening correctly?

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var logger = require('logger');
var bodyParserNew = require('body-parser');
var application_root = __dirname;
var path = require("path");
var util = require('util');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./privatekey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt')
};

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'site')));

//listener
app.post('/api/test', function (req, res) {
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log('/api/test');
        console.log(req.body);
    }); 

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
});

https.createServer(options,app).listen(8080);
console.log('listening on server 8080');
```

Snippet of payload I'm seeing:

```
��Qk�0��R��ْ,K��1$e!Y�Ä��2�����b��n)�e�7��:�ü�F7V���-
�?�3���G��� �
                 9���=#�4��hhv���k��Y�0�%Øq&�mÄ7�i�A�C>��A???h,�����1�5�����2Äe�<�?�����Q��
```

Comment: You're logging `req.body`, but your var with your accumulated body is just `body`.  What happens if you change `console.log(req.body);` to `console.log(body);`?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your `res.writeHead(200); res.end();` inside your `req.on('end')` callback, otherwise you're immediately sending the response before waiting for the request data.

Also, you don't need to be buffering the request data manually. Adding `app.use(bodyParserNew.json());` above the route will do this for you and provide `req.body` containing the parsed result. You can also set some [bodyParser.json() options](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions) if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and this works just fine in my case. In your example req.body should be just body. Like mscdex says, you can use middleware to parse the json for you. Here you have the code that works for me (it's almost the same as yours):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem')
};


//listener
app.post('/api/test', function (req, res) {
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log('/api/test');
        console.log(body);
    });

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
});

var https = require('https');
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```